# Does not register a service worker that controls page and 'start_url'

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

Next-pwa is not working in production.This is next.config.js

pwa: {
dest: "public",
runtimeCaching,
register: true,
skipWaiting: true,
scope: '/app',
sw: 'service-worker.js',
buildExcludes: [/middleware-manifest.json$/]
}

Comment: Can you show us the full code in `next.config.js`?

Comment: thank you, I fixed it . I registered service-worker in _app.js. Now all okey